# Accessing angular's scope within jquery code

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

hope I'm not duplicating an exisiting question...
I'm trying to access a function that is attached to "this" in my service,
However I have to do this from inside of an event binding of jQuery.

but I get an error of "undefined is not a function" from angular.

code:

```
app.service("whatever",function(){

this.instantiatePreIds = function () {
    /**whatever code**/
}

this.checkOnLoad = function () {

    angular.element(window).bind("popstate", function (e) {

        this.instantiatePreIds(); /***this row throws that error***/

    });
 }
});
```

Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fine I got it!!
all I had to do is to catch a reference of the scope into a var, and use it instead.

```
/*inside the service*/

var ref=this;

this.checkOnLoad = function () {

    angular.element(window).bind("popstate", function (e) {

        ref.instantiatePreIds(); 

    });
 }
```

Yesss!